# How to remove "<file_path>/file.py~Stashed changes" from git status

Tags: git, git-stash

After doing some git stashing and branch changes, I somehow have the following in my git status:

```
Untracked files:  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    "<file_path>/file.py~Stashed changes"
```

But when I try to do `git rm <file>` or `git add <file>`, I'm getting:

`fatal: pathspec '<file_path>/file.py~Stashed' did not match any files`

How do I remove this file path from my `git status`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use just `rm "<file_path>/file.py~Stashed changes"`

As per [the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm):

> `git rm` Remove files from the index, or from the working tree and the index. *git rm will not remove a file from just your working directory.*

Since your file is untracked, `git rm` won't remove it.

If you have many files to deal with, [have a look at](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) `git clean`.